# How to access JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I am trying to draw a simple pointer, 0..360 degrees, in a JPanel on a SingleFrameApplication.
I am using NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 since it has a nice Palette of Swing Containers, Controls, Menus, etc.
I'd like the DrawPointer interface to be something like this since there will be more than one [pointer]:

```
DrawPointer(JPanel panel, double degrees);
```

but the JPanel is declared private by IDE generated code like this:

```
public class MyView extends FrameView {
    public MyView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);
        initComponents();
        ...
    private void initComponents() {
        ...
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelA;
        ...
```

How do I access the JPanel to draw in it if it is private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that being `private` is your sole concern, you can change that in netbeans ,

> right click the component > customize code > at the bottom you have the option to change the declaration code.

Answer (score 0):

you add a method to your `MyView` class which returns `jPanelA` (for that matter there could already be a method like that, have you checked the autogenerated code?)